# PHP mysql multiple Select Query is not working

Tags: php, mysql

My sql Query is not working.
I need to `filter` a `data` with `Location` but it not works. Why this is not working

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM entries WHERE location 
IN ('chennai,Bangalore') AND en_id = 'test' AND date(datetime) 
BETWEEN '2015-10-02' AND '2015-10-31'";
```

Comment: or you can try **WHERE location like '%chennai%' or location like '%Bangalore%'** is good option if you match string

Comment: you forgot apostrophe IN ('chennai','Bangalore') AND

Answer (score 4):

You need to update your query

```
IN ('chennai,Bangalore')
```

into

```
IN ('chennai','Bangalore')
```

Comment: Please stop downvoting answer without posting reasons. Atleast post the reason for downvoting

Answer (score 1):

try this table and query and analyst it hope will help you
table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entries` (
 `id` int(15) NOT NULL,
 `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `en_id` varchar(25) NOT NULL ,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `entries`
--

 INSERT INTO `entries` (`id`, `location`, `en_id`, `date`) VALUES
 (1, 'chennai', 'test', '2015-10-31 12:53:38'),
 (2, 'Bangalore', 'test', '2015-10-31 12:53:38'),
 (3, 'chennai', 'test', '2015-10-13 12:53:38'),
 (4, 'chennai', 'test', '2015-10-05 12:53:38'),
 (5, 'chennai', 'test1', '2015-10-03 00:00:00'),
 (6, 'Bangalore', 'test', '2015-10-04 12:53:38'),
 (7, 'Bangalore', 'test1', '2015-10-03 00:00:00'),
 (8, 'chennai', 'test1', '2015-10-30 00:00:00'),
 (9, 'Bangalore', 'test1', '2015-10-30 00:00:00');
```

This is the query to get your desired result

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM entries WHERE location 
 IN ('chennai','Bangalore') AND en_id = 'test1' AND date(NOW()) 
 BETWEEN '2015-10-02' AND '2015-10-31'
```